# Stripe firebase extension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have a expo android app and react web app. Both the app uses phone authentication from firebase. When creating a new user, stripe extension creates a new user in stripe simultaneously. The issue is my customer logs primarily in android app and not in web app. Now I need to create a subscription for new user with a trial period. After the trail period I can ask my customer to pay the subscription from web app. How can I create new subscription with trial period from firebase function when a new user is created? Or is it possible to create subscription automatically for all new users with a particular subscription product and trial period without payment information?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to [create Subscription with trial period](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials). No payment method is required for the customer, but until the trail ends you will need to collect their payment info. Stripe has [a Doc explains this scenario](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#non-payment).